# Как установить php-ml?

Tags: php, composer

Установил через composer. Вроде всё ок. Установилось в директории, где лежит php.exe
Однако, во всех примерах кода (у них в документации) требуется **vendor/autoload.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Phpml\Classification\KNearestNeighbors;

$samples = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 2]];
$labels = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'];

$classifier = new KNearestNeighbors();
$classifier->train($samples, $labels);

echo $classifier->predict([3, 2]);
// return 'b'
```

У меня же его, нигде нет! И соответственно никакой скрипт не выполняется.

Его и у них даже на гитхабе нет, нигде нету этого файла. В чем смысл? Или я что-то не правильно сделал? Подскажите пожалуйста.

https://github.com/jorgecasas/php-ml - тут смотрел, нигде нет этого файла

Comment: несколько странно хранить php.exe в одной папке с самим кодом.

Comment: да я не шарю в этом компосере, не понимаю, чего в нем нашли люди. В чем смысл усложнять обычный процесс перетаскивания папок. Он только через php.exe работает, этот компосер

Comment: легкое обновление всех зависимостей в пакетах, автозагрузка и т.п. шляпа, +унификация для всех разработчиков. если под виндой работаете то путь к php.exe просто в PATH надо прописать. Композер запускаете в папке с проектом и создаст он вам там vendor директорию.